# loading a page in div using jquery but not work

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery, I used this code but it does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add_cl").click(function(){
            $("#formtag").load("main.php");
        });
    });
</script>
```

On clicking the button having `id="add_cl"` want to load `main.php` in `#formtag` like ajax. On clicking  it, it shows `main.php` page in live view in Dreamweaver but not in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Is 'main.php' still in the same folder as the html for this page when you're testing on the browser? Also you can check for ajax errors by adding a callback function and logging the server's response - http://api.jquery.com/load/. Your browser's web console might also already be showing some error, try opening it up and checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I suppose you're using Chrome. You should use a local server like Xampp to make this work locally. Or upload it to your online server to test. should work!
- Instead of using `localhost` try with: `127.0.0.1`
- Chrome fights a bug using AJAX due to same origin policy or something related to it, so don't get mad and use some other browser. P.S: I use XAMPP and Chrome, and AJAX works really well. hope it helps

**Related to your comment:**
to load different pages inside the same element try using the `data` attribute to store your URLs:

```
<button class="loader" data-loadpage="main.php"> Load main.php </button>
<button class="loader" data-loadpage="about.php"> Load about.php </button>
<button class="loader" data-loadpage="contact.php"> Load contact.php </button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loader").click(function(){
        $("#formtag").load( $(this).data('loadpage') );
    });
});
```

additionally you could try also `.empty()` to remove old content from your `#formtag`: 
`$("#formtag").empty().load( $(this).data('loadpage') );`

Comment: @sadi ok, instead of using `localhost` try with: `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @sadi As I said, Chrome fights a bug using AJAX due to *same origin pocicy* or something related to it, so don't get mad and use some other browser. P.S: I use XAMPP and Chrome, and AJAX works really well. hope it helps.

Comment: it work on firefox and IE now. now how can i load different pages in one tag.in "formtag" i want loading different pages by clicking differnt buttons.

Comment: @sadi just add multiple click handlers (or ask a new question)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/uZ5XS/

HTML:

```
<span id="load">Click to Load content</span>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="loadingGif">LOADING GIF!!!!</div>​
```

Script:

```
$('#load').click(function() {
    $('#test').html('');
    $('#loadingGif').show();
    $('#test').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/bozdoz/2XgVd/show/ a', function() {
        $('#loadingGif').hide();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Callback Function

If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add_cl").click(function() {
            $("#formtag").load("main.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });​
</script>
```

And please also check that Is 'main.php' still in the same folder as the html for this page when you're testing on the browser? Also you can check for ajax errors by adding a callback function and logging the server's respons

Comment: yes "main.php" is in the same folder.it give alert load was performed but not load the "main.php page".

Comment: Please try the edited code again and send me the error. and please also check the element name formtag is also exist in that page.

Comment: If you're going to quote the jQuery docs or someone's comment in your answer, it's polite to put it in quotation marks and attribute it to them. As a matter of fact, I'm pretty sure it's some kind of copyright issue otherwise...